# square point of sale/connect api - 2 devices?

Tags: square-connect

I work for a repair shop that recently decided to implement a square chip/card reader. Up to this point, we have been manually entering credit card numbers into our internal silverlight app running on a pc on our domain.
We ordered the square point of sale system that includes chip reader, ipad, stand, the whole bundle.

We looked at the square pos api, which targets iOS and Android platforms, but also has a Web api for non-native apps. The api is supposed to be able to switch control from our browser based app to the square app to allow a customer to swipe their card, and upon completion, the api switches control back to our app.

Since the system is based on web api calls, we envisioned initiating the sale from our app running on our pc by calling the api, and control would be passed to the square app on the ipad.

However, when we contacted square about this system, we were advised that our app and the square app had to be running on the same device (the ipad in this case).

But it's a web api. Geographical separation shouldn't matter.

Has anyone implemented a similar architecture with a square device? Or does anyone have a potential workaround?

Answer (score 0):

The web request must be initiated from the same device because it uses native App linking/ Intents to switch between the browser and the Square Point of Sale app. You can not currently initiate a transaction on a different device. The "web" in "web API" means that you are starting from a website (as opposed to a native application), not in that the request goes over the web.

Comment: what about hybrid applications using Apache Cordova (html, css, js) ?